# Detect which method called the routing condition in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm using Sinatra with namespace.
When I tried to use condition, I met a problem.

Here's the snippet of code

```
class MainApp < Sinatra::Base
  register Sinatra::Namespace
  set(:role) do |role|
    condition{
      ### DETECT WHERE THIS IS CALLED
      p role
      true
    }
  end

  namespace '/api', :role => :admin do
    before do
      p "before"
    end
    get '/hoo' do
      p "hoo"
    end
  end

  namespace '/api' do
    get '/bar' do
      p "bar"
    end
  end
end
```

The above code outputs following message to console when accessing `/api/hoo`

```
:admin
:admin
"before"
:admin
"hoo"
```

I could not understand why `:admin` is displayed three times. However, maybe one is from `namespace`, and other twos are from `before` and `get '/hoo'`.

On the other hand, accessing `/api/bar` shows `:admin` two times.

I just want to do the filtering only before `get '/hoo'`. Is there any idea?

NOTE: I don't wan't to change URL from `/api/hoo` to something like `/api/baz/hoo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can debug the steps using the `caller`:

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-caller

(Note: I wouldn't recommend to leave `caller` in production code unless you absolutely need it for introspection, because it's quite slow.)

Re the Sinatra filters in particular, note that you can at the very least qualify the route and conditions they apply to:

http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Filters

```
before '/protected/*' do
  authenticate!
end

before :agent => /Songbird/ do
  # ...
end
```

I can't recollect how to get the http method, but if you look at the sinatra source code you'll likely find it -- last I looked, I recollect each of `get`, `post`, etc. to forward their call to the same function, with a method parameter.

Comment: This in not the direct answer I supposed, but however thanks for advice, I'll give a try.